# How to return value from nested task in c++/cx?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, win-universal-app, c++-cx

I have a bunch of threaded tasks like this after each other:

```
create_task(somewinrtasyncfunction()).then([this(variable_that_the_last_task_returned)
{
    //task here
    return info;
}).then([this](info)
{
    //another task here
    return status});
```

Now I want to use `status` outside the tasks, in the function that called it. How would I access it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You `return` the task (or value) created by `create_task(...).then(...).then(...)`.

If you need to get the result synchronously, you can *try* calling `.get()` on the `task` but *that will **not** work on the main UI thread(s) of your application, and is not something you should do*. The code *might* work on a background thread today, but you might end up calling the function on the UI thread in the future -- perhaps by some very round-about fashion -- and then your app will crash. The only way to fix the app will be to re-engineer your code to be asynchronous... like it should have been in the first place.

Also, note that trying to do your own work-arounds to get the value synchronously (like calling `WaitForSingleObjectEx()` on an object signaled in the task) can deadlock the UI thread for many WinRT Async methods. **Don't do it!**

You should continue the asynchronous chain to act on the value. Here is a simple example; call `test()` from your main UI thread.

```
concurrency::task<int> get_double_async(int value)
{
  return concurrency::create_task(
    [value]()
  {
    return value * 2;
  });
}

// DON'T DO THIS - IT IS A BUG FARM WAITING TO HAPPEN!
int try_calling_get()
{
  auto value = 2;
  value = get_double_async(value).get(); // TODO: Don't do this!
  value = get_double_async(value).get(); // TODO: Don't do this!
  return value;
}

concurrency::task<int> do_it_properly()
{
  auto value = 2;
  return get_double_async(value).then([](int value)
  {
    return get_double_async(value).then([](int value)
    {
      return value;
    });
  });
}

void test()
{
  wchar_t buff[255];
  swprintf_s(buff, L"test() being called on thread %d.\r\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
  OutputDebugString(buff);

  // this will fail at runtime if called from UI thread
  try
  {
    auto x = try_calling_get();
  }
  catch (const concurrency::invalid_operation& op)
  {
    // "Illegal to wait on a task in a Windows Runtime STA"
    swprintf_s(buff, L"try_calling_get() threw '%hs'; thread is %d.\r\n",
      op.what(), GetCurrentThreadId());
    OutputDebugString(buff);
  }

  // this will "work", but only because it is forced into a threadpool thread
  concurrency::create_task([]
  {
    auto x = try_calling_get(); // TODO: Don't do this!
    wchar_t buff[255];
    swprintf_s(buff, L"try_calling_get() returned %d; thread is %d.\r\n",
      x, GetCurrentThreadId());
    OutputDebugString(buff);
  });

  // this is the preferred way to do it
  do_it_properly().then([](int x)
  {
    wchar_t buff[255];
    swprintf_s(buff, L"do_it_properly() returned %d; thread is %d.\r\n",
      x, GetCurrentThreadId());
    OutputDebugString(buff);
  });
}
```

Note that this example uses value-based continuations `.then([](int value){...})` rather than task-based continuations `.then([](task<int> value){...})`; you would use task-based continuations if you wanted control over things like exceptions.

Here's a sample run (the thread IDs will be different every time, and sometimes the last two will be the same)

```
test() being called on thread 3576.
First-chance exception at 0x77134598 in UniversalNativeApp.Windows.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Concurrency::invalid_operation at memory location 0x038CEC94.
try_calling_get() threw 'Illegal to wait on a task in a Windows Runtime STA'; thread is 3576.
try_calling_get() returned 8; thread is 5972.
do_it_properly() returned 8; thread is 9976.
```