# What are the benefits of returning a task from a function?

Tags: c++, task, c++-cx, ppl

I've seen create_task used in a couple ways:

```
void Bob()
{
    create_task() { /* do stuff */ }.then([](){ /* do more stuff */ });
}
```

and

```
task<void> Bob()
{
    return create_task() { /* do stuff */ }.then([](){ /* do more stuff */ });
}
```

Why bother returning the task (in the second example) when asynchronous behavior can be achieved with either approach?

Clarification: I'm **not** asking about the void return type specifically. It could be an int, object, or something else.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @R Sahu - Not sure how it's unclear; I'm asking when one would return a task object when it seems unnecessary to achieve asynchronous behavior. I've reworded the question to clarify this point.

Comment: It's unclear to me because there is no explanation of what `task` is and how it is used in your application.

Comment: This article, [Implementing the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/implementing-the-task-based-asynchronous-pattern) has a discussion that may be helpful.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about the case where the task has a void return type? Because it's obvious that if the task returns a value, you need the task object to get out the value. If not it could still be useful for checking if the task has completed.

Comment: @RSahu the question is very clear especially with the tags specified. Its a bit opinion oriented however the core question is what are the pros and cons of the two approaches.

Comment: @Sean Burton - "...it could still be useful for checking if the task has completed" - I think that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @SeanBurton it would seem that the `Task` object could also be used for further continuations as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void`/`task<void>` is a special case here, because you can magic a `void` from nowhere. You couldn't do the same with a `int`, `std::string` or similar.

```
void Bob()
{
    create_task() { /* do stuff */ }.then([](){ /* do more stuff */ });
}
```

After this has returned `/* do stuff */` and `/* do more stuff */` have started, and any handle on their progress is discarded.

```
task<void> Bob()
{
    return create_task() { /* do stuff */ }.then([](){ /* do more stuff */ });
}
```

After this has returned `/* do stuff */` and `/* do more stuff */` have started, and you have a handle to wait for them to finish.

```
int Alice()
{
    return create_task() { /* do stuff */ }.then([](){ /* do more stuff */ return 42; }).get();
}
```

After this has returned `/* do stuff */` and `/* do more stuff */` have **finished**, with a final result available.

```
task<int> Alice()
{
    return create_task() { /* do stuff */ }.then([](){ /* do more stuff */ return 42; });
}
```

After this has returned `/* do stuff */` and `/* do more stuff */` have started, and you have a handle to wait for them to finish, and get the result.

Comment: Thanks, Caleth. Can you add to your answer an example of using the handle to wait for the finish & get the result?

Comment: See also [Task Parallelism (Concurrency Runtime)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd492427(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: @phonetagger the examples in [Composing Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd492427(v=vs.120).aspx#composing_tasks) are common patterns, starting multiple tasks then proceeding when they are done

Comment: See as well [How to return value from nested task in c++/cx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323277/how-to-return-value-from-nested-task-in-c-cx)